# The brake pedal goes to the floor after starting the engine

Tags: brakes

I am currently in the process of rebuilding a wrecked truck. I have replaced all of the 
- brake lines 
- calipers
- wheel cylinders, 
- pads, 
- shoes,
- brake booster, 
- master cylinder

However when I start the engine the pedal still goes flat to the floor. I have  bypassed the anti-lock system and still goes to the floor. I have bleed the system both manually and with an vacuum system, still having this problem used  3 boosters and 3 different master cylinders.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: what is your make/model/year of vehicle?  Is it all stock parts?  What did you use to vacuum all the fluid out?  Welcome to Stack Exchange.  Cheers!

Comment: If it's a GM you probably have to actuate the bypass modulator valve.

Comment: If it's a modern car the pedals may have collapsed if it is wrecked, which could mean you have to replace the pedals

Comment: Is the brake pedal going to the floor without even pressing it?

Comment: Are the brakes working when the pedal is down?

Comment: Did you bench bleed the master?

Comment: Did you physically bypass the ABS, or just disconnect the power?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Brake pedal goes all the way to floor, after ABS was activated](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/7819/brake-pedal-goes-all-the-way-to-floor-after-abs-was-activated)